# Regex to get everything except strings between parenthesis

Tags: regex, string

From this string:

```
asdfhjlfbvj(1dszfkl)asdfjklugnnbcvklbc(2adfsfhj)fklajsdflkjasdf(3asdf)bvcxv
```

With this:

```
\\(.*?\\)
```

you get (1dszfkl), (2adfsfhj) and (3asdf)

How to get asdfhjlfbvj, asdfjklugnnbcvklbc, fklajsdflkjasdf and bvcxv?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match non-parentheses characters, with lookahead for `(` or the end of the string:

```
[^()]+(?=\(|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/1XOjjA/1

Or, if you can use `\K`, to be more efficient, match parentheses and what's contained in them and then use `\K` to forget:

```
(?:\([^)]+\)\K)?[^(]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/1XOjjA/2

Comment: I don't know the second one, working in the website, it doesn't work in python (even scaping characters): (?:\\([^)]+\\)\K)?[^\\(]+ it just shows: ['asdfhjlfbvj', '1dszfkl)asdfjklugnnbcvklbc', '2adfsfhj)fklajsdflkjasdf', '3asdf)bvcxv']
import re

regex = r'(?:\\([^)]+\\)\K)?[^\\(]+'

m = re.findall(regex, line)

print m

Comment: Python's native `re` module doesn't support `\K` - for that, you'll have to use Pypi's regex module instead.